# Why I can't show the string normally in gdb?

Tags: gdb

source:

```
char *pid_file...
```

gdb:

```
(gdb) p (char *)pid_file
$47 = 0x423047 "H\215\005\366i "
(gdb) x/s pid_file
0x423047 <__libc_csu_init+55>:   "H\215\005\366i "
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like pid_file has not been assigned to any valid string yet, and points to arbitrary "garbage". You've elided the most relevant part ;-(